# Were "en" and "y" always used in French?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, étymologie, histoire

To a beginning learner like me, these two pronouns, *en* and *y*, are so quintessentially French that they seem to have been part of the language since its very inception, really.

However, I have no knowledge of the history of these typically French linguistic structures; nor do I know when they first entered the language.

So my question is: As Latin, the language from which French evolved, seems to have nothing similar to either *en* or *y*, what is then the linguistic source for these pronouns in French, and when were they first introduced into the language? (So a very concise introduction to the history of these words would be greatly appreciated).

Comment: "This question may already have an answer here: Quelle est la différence entre les pronoms « en » et « y » ? 5 answers" That question was about the grammatical functions of these two words, not their etymology and history. Downvoter, have you really not understood the fundamental difference between _function_ and _history_? Or have you seen a single note on the etymology of these words in this question which you think may have anticipated mine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grevisse, le bon Usage (qui a en tout douze pages sur *en* et *y* dans la 12<sup>ième</sup> édition)

> *En* vient de l'adverbe latin *inde* « de là ».  Pour *y* (ordinairement écrit *i* en ancien français), les étymologistes sont partagés : les uns proposent l'adverbe latin *ibi* « là » (certainement représenté par la forme *iv* des *Serments de Strasbourg*) ; d'autres l'adverbe latin *hic* « ici ».

As they come from adverbs, and behave both like adverbs and pronouns, they are sometimes called *adverbes pronominaux* or *pronoms adverbiaux*.